# How to display ALL raster output from batch processing in ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.4, batch, display

I am batch converting ASCII files into ArcGIS geodatabase using a simple ASCII to raster model. I was using ArcGIS 10.3.1 and everything was running great, all my surfaces/files were showing up at the end of the batch processing in my table of content/display with the proper symbology etc.

My company upgraded to ArcGIS 10.4 and now only the last raster in my batch list shows up in my display despite having all the options turned on for "Add result to display" (in both my model and in Geoprocessing Options).

Here is a screenshot of my model, output raster parameters, Geoprocessing parameters, batch window and resulting map window:
[image]
I only have two files in this exemple but I'm usually working with with tens of new files every day.

My input file is in ESRI ASCII format.

I did all possible combinations of "Add to Display" options i.e. only the first output, only the last output, all three.

But in the end only the last file in the batch list gets displayed.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Please [edit] your question to include details about your model, including a screenshot and info about your inputs for the tools.